# Functional component not rerendering, even passing [sum] in useEffect dependency as it changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

Even on click of button, the `sum` variable changes to `29.98`, but though I am using `useEffect` hook, and I've added dependency as `[sum]`, so that if value of num changes `let sum = 0`, as I click button, and sum now becomes as 29.98, so re-render should happen and I should now see updated value on UI, but it still shows 0, I think component does not Rerender. Why?

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'; 
import './SelectEx1.css'

const SelectEx1 = (props) => {

let data = [
    {
        id: 1,
        title: "Milk",
        price: 15.99,
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        title: "Bread",
        price: 13.99,
    },
];
let sum = 0; 

useEffect(()=>{}, [sum]);

const handleClick = () => {
  console.log(data);
  data.map((item) => {
    sum = (sum + item.price)
  });
}

  return (
    <div>
      <p>hello, {sum}</p>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>click-me</button>
    </div>
  )
}
export default SelectEx1;
```

Comment: `sum` should be state, so that you can set your sum state which will inform react that it needs to re-render. Also, [don't use `.map()`](https://thenewtoys.dev/blog/2021/04/17/misusing-map/) for looping only, use `.forEach()` (or in this case, `.reduce()` might be better). [`useEffect()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) doesn't cause your component to re-render, its the setting of state which does that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you want is

```
const [sum, setSum] = useState(0); 
...
const handleClick = () => {
  console.log(data);
  const total = data.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
  setSum(total);
}
```

So that `handleClick` will trigger a change in state, which triggers rerender.
Putting `sum` into the dependency list of `useEffect` merely triggers the function(first parameter) in `useEffect` when `sum` is changed. Since the first paramter is an empty function, it does nothing when `sum` is changed.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of defining `sum` as variable make it state. Because state updates trigger re-renders. And call `setSum` inside `handleClick` function to change the state `sum`'s value which will cause re-render and you'll get to see the updated value on the UI:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'; 
import './SelectEx1.css'

const data = [
    {
        id: 1,
        title: "Milk",
        price: 15.99,
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        title: "Bread",
        price: 13.99,
    },
];
 
const SelectEx1 = (props) => {

const [sum, setSum] = React.useState(0)

const handleClick = () => {
  const total = data?.reduce(function (previousValue, currentValue) {
    return previousValue + currentValue.price
  }, 0)
  setSum(total)
}

  return (
    <div>
      <p>hello, {sum}</p>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>click-me</button>
    </div>
  )
}

export default SelectEx1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `useEffect`, put `sum` in `useState` and change `onClick` like below:

```
const [sum,setSum] = useState(0);
const handleClick = () => {
  const reducer = (previousValue, currentValue) => previousValue +
  currentValue.price;
  setSum(data.reduce(reducer,0))
}
```